# Connecting to a dummy ldap3 Active Directory server

Tags: python-3.x, active-directory, ldap3

I was reading on how to use [ldap3](https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3) for mocking, and got this:

```py
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, OFFLINE_AD_2012_R2, MOCK_SYNC


mock_server = Server('dummy_ad', get_info=OFFLINE_AD_2012_R2)
mock_conn   = Connection(mock_server, client_strategy=MOCK_SYNC)
mock_conn.bind()
```

Is it possible to have just the server run in one Python shell with some dummy users/passwords, and then connect and test authentication from another shell via ldap3?

Context - I want to add active directory authentication to a django app using `ldap3`. This is meant to be a first tier for testing the authentication function.

Answer (score 0):

## ldap3 is a LDAP client library

The example of using `client_strategy=MOCK_SYNC` shows how to mock ldap3 in the django app itself. It **does not** actually run an ldap server in another process.

You can use the `client_strategy=MOCK_SYNC` to instantiate the mock `Connection` in the django app and feed it entries like so:

```
connection.strategy.add_entry('cn=user0,ou=test,o=lab', 
   {'userPassword': 'test0000', 'sn': 'user0_sn', 'revision': 0})
```